# How to know if Garbage Collector was run during my application runtime?

Tags: java

Is there any way through which we can find out if Java Garbage Collector was run during an application's run time?

Paul

Comment: How would that information be useful? Maybe you could explained your problem from the beginning.

Comment: Are you trying to track down a bottleneck and suspect Garbage Collection is eating up your time? Have you tried profiling your program? A profiler would allow you to see what threads are running, including when and for how long garbage collection is happening.

Comment: Just for fun, add the following at the beginning of your stuff:         new Object(){protected void finalize() throws Throwable {System.out.println("GC was here! :)");}};

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use JVM arguments `-verbose:gc` and `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` to see what the GC is doing. Take a look at section 3.2 of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

Answer (score 1):

```
List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> gcBeans = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gcBean : gcBeans) {
    long numCollections = gcBean.getCollectionCount(); // it's possible for this to return -1 for a given collector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you could do it with a [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

```
// beginning of application
   WeakReference<Object> ref = new WeakReference < > ( new Object ( ) ) ;

// ....

// end of application
   if ( ref . get ( ) == null ) { System . out . println ( "gc" ) ; }
   else { System . out . println ( "no gc" ) ; }
```